# Laravel way to use a custom pivot table that accepts null values, using attach does not work with null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to be able to add in an user to the pivot table that does not yet have an ID. Later when that user becomes a member I can update their record with their ID.

Here are my models:

```
class Group extends Eloquent {

public function members()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'member')
            ->withPivot('first','last','favorite_food')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}

class User extends Eloquent {

    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Group')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

This works:

```
 $group->members()->attach(Auth::user()->id, array('first' => $new_array[$key][0], 'last' =>     
 $new_array[$key][1], 'favorite_food' => $new_array[$key][2]));
```

This does not work, but I really wish it would:

```
 $group->members()->attach(null, array('first' => $new_array[$key][0], 'last' => $new_array[$key]  
 [1], 'favorite_food' => $new_array[$key][2]));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be going about this the wrong way, a better solution in my mind would be to make your "temporary" users actual users in your database, but just add a "temporary" flag to mark them as such, you can always have a routine to clear out the temporary users based on their updated_at timestamp.

This would solve your null problem at the same time.

Comment: Yah there is definitely a need to re-evaluate what is going on here. I ran it by an associate waiting to see what he comes up with. Thanks for the advice. I simplified the setup to make asking the question less verbose.